# Is it possible to clear message history in gVIM?

Tags: vim

In gVIM i use `echomsg` command to output debug messages from my scripts (for debug purpose) and `messages` command to view them. All works fine, but vim messanging facility displays **all** messages - from all scripts, system, notifications etc. Is it some way to clear messages list (manually before i perform action i want to debug) so i can easily see messages from my script? Or maybe some filter i can use to view only my messages?

Comment: It seems there's no way to clear `message-history`

Comment: Maybe where is over way to post debug messages instead?

Comment: @EyeofHell Something like `command -nargs=1 -bar Echo :let g:messages=get(g:, 'messages', [])+[<q-args>]`. This will put debug messages into `g:messages` list (and create it if required).

Comment: @ZyX Thanks. Can you please post it as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK you can’t clear message history, but you can use your own command instead of `:echom`, for example:

```
command -nargs=1 -bar Echo :let g:messages=get(g:, 'messages', [])+[<q-args>]
```

or, maybe better,

```
command -nargs=1 -bar Echo :let g:messages=get(g:, 'messages', [])+[eval(<args>)] | echom <args>
```

First one is not evaluating its argument and thus cannot be a replacement of `:echom`, second is, but note that while with `:echom` `:echom 1 2` and `:echom 1.' '.2` produces the same output, with `:Echo` first will be an error forcing you to use the second form.

Both commands will put messages into `g:messages` variable, creating it if necessary. To clear history simply use

```
unlet g:messages
```

Comment: For newer versions of vim, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777871/237059

Answer (score 38):

as of vim [7.4.1735](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v7.4.1735) you can do `:messages clear` to clear the history.

Answer (score -1):

This command fills in empty messages to clear the message history.

`command! MessageClear for n in range(200) | echom "" | endfor`

[Source](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/osyo-manga/20130502/1367499610)